# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects vs new when reusing

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsmutablearray

Under ARC, would `removeAllObjects` on a `NSMutableArray` be more intense for the CPU (releasing the objects individually explicitly) than simply doing `myArray = [NSMutableArray new];` and just let ARC catch the whole released memory-block on it's next release round?

I could test this with 2 pieces of code, but due to optimization and such I'm really just curious about the mechanics. From a `C` perspective it feels like calling all objects to be released sounds more intense, but maybe the `dealloc` tree in Objective-C might be efficient enough for ARC to do this at an equal speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some code has to loop through that array inside `NSMutableArray`, and call `release` on all its non-`nil` objects. If there is a difference between what code does it, inside ARC or inside `NSMutableArray`, it should not be noticeable, because the expensive part is not the loop overhead, it's the actual call of `release` and potential deallocation following it.

There is a more significant difference, though: when you call `removeAllObjects`, the array retains its internal storage, so it would not have to grow its internal size the next time you start appending to it. If your usage pattern calls for repeated addition of large number of items to the same array, calling `removeAllObjects` may save you some allocation/reallocation cycles.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I only have 2 really big arrays that would assign many (thousands) of entries. I'm gonna do some specific tests to see if it will matter performance-wise (even if it's marginal) to re-use them with `removeAllObject`.